# How to render Dynamic html with data bindings

Tags: angular, typescript

I get some html from backend and it has tags with property bindings for example

```
fetchedHtml = `<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
  [customColors]="customColors"
  [showDataLabel]="true"
  [results]="BarChartDataInput"
  [xAxis]="true"
  [yAxis]="true"
  [legend]="false"
  [showXAxisLabel]="false"
  [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
  [showYAxisLabel]="true"
  [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
>
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
  `;
```

Now I want to render that html inside a dynamically generated or normal component, I saw a good example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-raw-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-template.component.ts
In  the example he's using 
`compile.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync()` which requires NgModule to be passed as an argument but instead of creating a dynamic NgModule, I want to know how I can directly insert a component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` within the Angular DomSanitizer.

Just inject it into the component you want to use the **HTML** like so:

```
constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

then inject the html into your template like below:

```
<span [innerHtml]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrusHtml(YOUR_HTML_STRING_HERE)"></span>
```

For more info see the documentation: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: This is just printing the string as it is